# Find the end offset of a matched string or regex

Tags: python, regex, string

`str.find()` returns the beginning offset of a match in a string.
How can one get the end offset?

I know that one way is to add it to the length of the match. But is there a way to get it directly?

e.g.

```
>>> a = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'
>>> a.find('ipsum')
6
```

What I want is:

```
>>> a.find('ipsum')+len('ipsum')
11
```

This is trivial in case of `str.find()`. But gets more important in case of `regex`, since the length of the matched expression is not known beforehand.

Comment: `str.rfind('ipsum')` find the end offset..

Comment: What is `re.find()`?

Comment: @letsc str.rfind() is same as str.find() just starts checking from end of the string and finishes in the beginning. It still returns the beginning of a match.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The objects returned by the `search` and `match` functions in Python's `re` module have a `span()` method that returns the start and end positions of the matched regular expression:

```
>>> import re
>>> a = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'
>>> re.search('ipsum', a).span()
(6, 11)
>>> re.search('sum.*sit', a).span()
(8, 21)
```

The start and end positions can also be returned individually with `.start()` and `.end()`.